# How to pass id and card content of a clicked card to the another component in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

i have three components icons.vue which contains icons and dropdown also and this component is the child component of DisplayNotes.vue, Now when a user clicks on any card DeleteNote-option(which present inside of icons.vue)that card id and content should be passed to the another component DeleteNote.vue,How to pass the particular clicked card[[visit my output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiOLv.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiOLv.png) data to the DeleteNote.vue component,please help me to fix this issue

`icons.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="footer">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <i clss="fas fa-image"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <i @click="myFunction();" class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        <div ref="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="">DeleteNote</a>
            <a href="">ChangeLabel</a>
            <a href="">Add drawing</a>
            <a href="">Make a Copy</a>
            <a href="">Show Checkboxes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        myFunction(event) {
            this.$refs.myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
            return event;
            // document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.footer i {
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
}
.footer .fa-bell {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.footer .fa-user {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-palette {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-image {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-archive {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-ellipsis-v {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}
.dropdown {

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    margin-left: 40%;

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(241, 234, 234)
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard" :cardContent="cardContent" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,
        UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
            clickedCard: '',
            cardContent: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id) {
            var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
            this.clickedCard = id;
            // this.card.content = this.notes.filter((note) => note.id === id);
            var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        },
        
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

`DeleteNote.vue`[i want o pass the clicked card id(click of DeleteNote inside dropdown inside icons.vue)]

```
<template>
<div v-if="flag==false" class="update">
    <form class="update-note" @submit.prevent autocomplete="off">
        <input name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea name="content" v-model="body" style="resize: none" placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3"></textarea>
        <div class="btm-icons">
            <icons />
            <button id="btn-section" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();flip();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import icons from './icons.vue'
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    components: {
        icons
    },
    props: ['cardId', 'cardContent'],
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            body: '',
            flag: false,
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.title = this.cardContent.title;
        this.body = this.cardContent.body;
    },
    methods: {
        flip() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                id: this.cardId,
                title: this.title,
                body: this.body
            }
            service.userUpdateNotes(userData).then(response => {
                alert("Note updated  successfully");
                return response;
            }).catch(error=>{
                alert("Error ");
                return error;
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/UpdateNotes.scss";
</style>
```

`router.js`[routing path for deleteNote.vue]

```
 {
        path:'/trash',
        component:DeleteNote
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate props in your routes

```
{
   path: '/trash',
   component: DeleteNote,
   name: 'DeleteNote',
   props: true
 },
```

Pass props to the icons component. From the icons component the pass the cardId and cardContent to the DeleteNote component using router-link.

Comment: Hello @wanje,Thanks for your response if i used this props:true it's not working because  i am not passing any  props inside the icons.vue component

Comment: Where do you want to pass the props

Comment: Hai @wanje, iw ant to get the id when user clicks on the DeleteNote in icon section it will get the card id and that id should be passed to the DeleteNote.vue component

Comment: Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\VICKY\Desktop\8\vue-fundoo\src\components\icons.vue
  24:17  error  The "cardId" property should be a constructor       vue/require-prop-type-constructor
  25:22  error  The "cardContent" property should be a constructor  vue/require-prop-type-constructor

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)

Comment: inorder to place router.js can we pass as a props filed into the DeleteNote.vue component

Comment: icons.vue component @wanje

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234051/discussion-between-wanje-and-sravani).